# With Langchain, how can I change the OpenAI API key at runtime?

Tags: python, fastapi, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

#### Context

I'm working with Langchain Expression Language (LCEL) in Python.

I'm using the `ChatOpenAI` class ([source code](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/community/langchain_community/chat_models/openai.py#L150)) within a FastAPI API. The code initializes at startup and then the chain is called with various arguments as requests flow in. I want to pass in different api keys at runtime, depending on the task I'm performing. `ConfigurableField` ([docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/how_to/configure)) allows me to change any config except `openai_api_key`.

**Is there something in the codebase that forbids this? How can I change the `openai_api_key` at runtime?**

#### This works

```
model = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0).configurable_fields(
    temperature=ConfigurableField(
        id="llm_temperature",
        name="LLM Temperature",
        description="The temperature of the LLM",
    )
)
model.with_config(configurable={"llm_temperature": 0.9}).invoke("foo_prompt")
```

#### But this doesn't

(It uses "placeholderkey" instead of the desired "somevalidapikey")

```
model = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key="placeholderkey").configurable_fields(
    openai_api_key=ConfigurableField(
        id="openai_api_key",
        name="API Key",
        description="The API key used when making a call to OpenAI",
    )
)
model.with_config(configurable={"openai_api_key": somevalidapikey}).invoke("foo_prompt")
```

#### Possible root cause?

A potential culprit for the `openai_api_key`'s silent exclusion would be `lc_secrets` which makes `openai_api_key` non-serializable, but I don't know if that actually has an impact.

From the [ChatOpenAI class](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/5396604ef4822abdc812baadec456af072d5f592/libs/community/langchain_community/chat_models/openai.py#L166C1-L169C1):

```py
    @property
    def lc_secrets(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {"openai_api_key": "OPENAI_API_KEY"}
```

###### I believe the relevant code is here:

[Source: ChatOpenAI Class](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/5396604ef4822abdc812baadec456af072d5f592/libs/community/langchain_community/chat_models/openai.py#L150)

###### and here:

[Source: RunnableSerializable](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/5396604ef4822abdc812baadec456af072d5f592/libs/community/langchain_community/chat_models/openai.py#L150)

Thank you for any support - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your exact error here? Try upgrading to the latest version of Langchain.
This appears to work in the LangServe scenario:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langserve/blob/54725a91edece67a61ac880f9f02239b6d81dd42/examples/configurable_chain/server.py#L104-L111

You can see lc_secrets is in Serializable:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/a84a3add2503d2ee5d781fd278d9eca7e11a8341/libs/core/langchain_core/load/serializable.py#L69